# How to find out what floods the terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, aix

When logged in via SSH to an AIX 6.1:

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # 
   Message from root on SERVER (UNKNOWN) [Fri Sep 18 08:00:17 2015] ...
Message from qdaemon:

: (WARNING) Connection to server failed.
rembak: errno = 81: No route to host
<EOT>

   Message from root on SERVER (UNKNOWN) [Fri Sep 18 08:00:17 2015] ...
Message from qdaemon:
/usr/lib/lpd/rembak -T20 -S xx10 -P xx10 -N /usr/lib/lpd/bsdshort /var/spool/qdaemon/PRINTERNAME <EOT>

   Message from root on SERVER (UNKNOWN) [Fri Sep 18 08:00:17 2015] ...
Message from qdaemon:
Queue xx10:@xx10 went down, job is still queued:
  Backend: /usr/lib/lpd/rembak -T20 -S xx10 -P xx10 -N /usr/lib/lpd/bsdshort \
                    /var/spool/qdaemon/PRINTERNAME 
  Backend Exit Value: EXITFATAL (0100)
  Job Submit Time: Sep 11 14:54:52 2015,  Current Time: Sep 18 08:00:17 2015
Use local problem reporting procedures.
<EOT>

0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

**Question**: How can I find out, what is flooding the screen/terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `qdaemon` is spamming messages. `qdaemon` handles printing primarily. There are details here on where `qdaemon` is configured to do this: http://ps-2.kev009.com/tl/techlib/manuals/adoclib/aixbman/printrgd/qdaemonb.htm

> The qdaemon print spooler always uses the sysnot routine to send messages.
>
> The backend can send messages directly to the user with the sysnot routine. The sysnot routine can either mail the message to the user or write the message to the user's terminal. The sysnot routine is called with the following syntax:
>
> The value of the pref parameter should be DOMAIL or DOWRITE. DOMAIL mails the error message to the user. DOWRITE writes the message to the user's terminal if the user is logged on. If the user is not logged on, the message is mailed to the user. The DOMAIL and DOWRITE constants are defined in the /usr/include/IN/backend.h file.

Comment: it's not enough to devnull the "enable" command since qdaemon prints the messages... best solution is to fix the printer or modify the syslog/console settings